# Why is my 12VDC LED flood light flashing when powered by a LED magnetic driver?

Tags: lighting, led

I just bought a new outdoor LED Flood lights which i plan to use on a field. However, when connected to a power source, the lights keep flashing and has a humming noise.
The flood lights are 12vdc @ 13A and In order to power the flood lights, i bought an LED magnetic driver (200watts, 12v). 
what can i do to prevent the flashing and be able to utilize the flood lights?

Comment: What are the specs of the transformer? Flashing and buzzing can be indicative of an impedance matching issue.

Comment: input: 120VAC 60Hz

Comment: @ Comintern output: 12VDC

Comment: P/N M200L 12DC 200W MAX

Answer (score 1):

If it's a good quality power supply, the pulsing means the power supply is possibly overloaded. It's the power supply's, method of telling you that, which is called "hiccuping." A load of 156W may be too close to 200W. You should allow for load + 20% when choosing a power supply.